# Running app in Debug via Xcode vs running app manually

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a Cocoa application. It runs fine via `XCode 6`, but when I run it manually via `Finder`, it behaves very strange: it seems that only the static `XIB` loads, no other code gets `executed`.

Do I need to sign it in order to work? I also tried archiving. For any clues, this is the code that executes first:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:verb];
        NSData *data = [qs dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *resSrt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", responseData];
```

Yes, there are HTTP requests made first in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` for the design to change.

Thank you!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I use `dispatch_queue_t` and `dispatch_async` for those requests, so I am not blocking the main thread.

Comment: Its blocking the app delegate method like that a good idea?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use `dispatch_queue_t` and `dispatch_async` for those requests, so I am not blocking the main thread.

Comment: Are there any messages from the app in the console log? /Applications/Utilities/Console.app is your friend.

Comment: I am using `NSLog`, but I don't know how to see the log without running the app via XCode.

Comment: I just told you. I even gave you the path to Console.app. Also, your app may log things to the console whether you use NSLog or not. The system may be telling you what's going wrong at launch.

Comment: Thank you! Got to the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually having problems with some inexistent files.

Comment: That's a really great answer and will help many people.  Instead you should have simply removed your question.